# Mono.Cecil create new instructions

Tags: c#, opcode, mono.cecil, operand

I have a little problem.
I am trying to insert a Collection of Instructions with Mono.Cecil in the Method I have created.

```
Collection<Instruction> InstructionList = new Collection<Instruction>();
```

To add a normal instruction which has no operand like for example "Ret" or "ldarg.0" I just do this:

```
InstructionList.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
```

But I have problems creating an Instruction which has an Operand like these (Image):

http://puu.sh/bzWi8/710c8008df.png

Can someone explain me how to add an Instruction with these operands, like the ldsfld empty string or br.s or callvirt.

I dont know how to do this.

My attempt was this:

```
InstructionList.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldsfld, ModuleDef.Import(typeof(System.String))));
```

But that throws an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Mono.Cecil.dll
Additional information: OpCode

Can someone explain me how to add these "more complex" instructions?

Comment: You need to give it 2 operands, ie a type and a value

Comment: and how would this value look like? (Sorry I am not so experienced with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InstructionList.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

it's should be

```
InstructionList.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret, null));
```